# MIT Python course 6.00.1X Lecture 8 Converting letter grades to numeric grades by using exception clause

Tags: python, python-3.x

This issue is from MIT Python course 6.00.1X, Lectrue 8. I have tried two slightly different pieces of code. Both of them are for computing the average grade of each student.

The first code does not take into account that there might be letter grades, the second code does. Actually, I expected to get lower grades for the student Wilma when running the second code. Because I set up returning 90.0 for letter grade 'A' in the second one. However, the result shows that in the second code, Wilma's average grade is even higher than the first grade,which is 25.0 compared with 17.466666666666665 in the first code.

I cannot figure out where goes wrong. I really appreciate any help and suggestion.

```py
#the first code
def getsubjectStats(subject, weights):
    return[[elt[0], elt[1], avg(elt[1], weights)]
           for elt in subject]

def dotProduct(a, b):
    result = 0.0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        result += a[i]*b[i]
    return result

def avg(grades, weights):
    try:
        return dotProduct(grades, weights)/len(grades)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('no grades data')
        return 0.0


test = [[['fred', 'flintstone'], [10.0, 5.0, 85.0]],
        [['barney', 'rubble'], [10.0, 8.0, 74.0]],
        [['wilma', 'flintstone'], [8.0, 10.0, 96.0]],
        [['dino'], []]]
weights = [.3, .2, .5]

print(getsubjectStats(test, weights))

#the second code
def getSubjectStats1(subject,weights):
    return [[elt[0], elt[1], avg1(elt[1], weights)]
           for elt in subject]
def dotProduct1(a, b):
    result = 0.0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        result += a[i] * b[i]
    return result
def avg1(grades, weights):
    try:
        return dotProduct1(grades, weights)/len(grades)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('no grades date')
        return 0.0
    except TypeError:
        newgrades = [convertLetterGrade(elt) for elt in grades]
        return dotProduct1(newgrades, weights)/len(newgrades)

def convertLetterGrade(grade):
    if type(grade) == int:
        return grade
    elif grade == 'A':
        return 90.0
    else:
        return 60.0

test0 = [[['fred', 'flintstone'], [10.0, 5.0, 85.0]],
        [['barney', 'rubble'], [10.0, 8.0, 74.0]],
        [['wilma', 'flintstone'], [8.t0, 10.0, 'A']],
        [['dino'], []]]
weights0 = [.3, .2, .5]

print(getSubjectStats1(test0, weights0))


I expect: 

the first one:
no grades data
[[['fred', 'flintstone'], [10.0, 5.0, 85.0], 15.5], [['barney', 'rubble'], [10.0, 8.0, 74.0], 13.866666666666667], 
[['wilma', 'flintstone'], [8.0, 10.0, 96.0], 17.466666666666665], [['dino'], [], 0.0]]

the second one:
...[['wilma', 'flintstone'], [8.0, 10.0, 'A'], 16.466666666666665]...

Actually, the first one meets my expectation, but actual output of the second one is ... [['wilma', 'flintstone'], [8.0, 10.0, 'A'], 25.0]...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `convertLetterGrade()` you are checking if `grade` is an `int` but the `grade` argument passed is a `float`. Therefore, the else condition is called and the numeric grades are converted to `60.0`.

To fix, in `convertLetterGrade()` change

`if type(grade) == int:`

to

`if type(grade) == int or type(grade) == float:`